# Tools to Convert C# to Managed C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, decompiler

I have a few .NET portable libraries written in C# which I need to port to Qt (C++). Since many of the classes don't really depend on .NET framework classes to a large extent, I thought it would be good strategy to use a tool to convert the C# code to Managed C++ first and then use that as the base for the porting it for use in Qt rather than rewriting the whole thing in C++

Are there any free tools to convert C# code or decompile a built assembly to Managed C++?

Answer (score 3):

> Since many of the classes don't really depend on .NET framework classes to a large extent, I thought it would be good strategy to use a tool to convert the C# code to Managed C++ first and then use that as the base for the porting it for use in Qt rather than rewriting the whole thing in C++

This is an error in reasoning. **Managed C++ is not C++**. Just because they're syntactically similar does not make the process of moving code across easier, on the contrary, you're making things unnecessarily harder for yourself.

The first thing that comes to mind is memory management. Your Managed C++ project will use GC object references (the `^` type) which cannot be easily converted to C++ memory-management semantics, nor is this something that can be done automatically unless you have your own Garbage Collection library you're prepared to weave into your existing program.

There is more to .NET than the framework classes, but consider the runtime environment. I've already touched on the GC, but what about Exceptions? Threading? The ABI? And so on.

You're better off rewriting it in pure idiomatic C++ rather than creating a mess that tries to straddle the CLR and pretend-C++.

Comment: Thanks for your Inputs. I do understand what you are trying to say and I have already considered it. But as it stands, the projects I am trying to convert have very trivial logic, but only contain a large number of classes which makes it tedious to rewrite manually. They don't have any threading or exception handling involved.

Comment: @DarthCorder If you have a lot of POCO classes than you can just copy+paste them into C++ and use some regex-based Find+Replace operations to make them syntactically conformant and compile.